# Query jpql to get value of table generated by ManyToMany association

Tags: mysql, jboss7.x, jpql, ejb-3.1

I have table on mysql generated by ManyToMany association. This table is `user_carrier` but when I run this query:

```
select c from client c
inner join c.utilisateur_transportcat utc 
inner join utc.transportcat tc
inner join tc.transport t
where t.intitule like 'byroad'
```

I get this error:

> :table user_carrier is not mapped

I think it's because it is not a class and it's just a table association that was generated by the ManyToMany association, but what can I do?

the class carrier is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TransportCat")
public class TransportCat {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer IdTransportCat;
    private String Intitule;
    @Lob @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
    private String Description;
    private String iconImage;
    private boolean Statut;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="IdTransport")
    private Transport transport;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="listTransportTrCat")
    private List<Client> listClient=new ArrayList<Client>();
```

The table user is :

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="client")
public class Client extends Utilisateur{

    //champs client privé
    private String Nom;
    private String Prenom;

    //question 
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="client",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
        private  List<Question> listeQuestion=new ArrayList<Question>();

    //liste des abonnements d'un utilisateur
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="pk.client",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval=true)
        private List<Commission_Client> listeCommissionClient=new ArrayList<Commission_Client>();

    /*@OneToMany(mappedBy="pk.client",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Abon_Comm_Client> listeAbonnement=new ArrayList<Abon_Comm_Client>();*/


    //liste des  factures
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="client",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Facture> listeFacture=new ArrayList<Facture>();

    //geolocalisation
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="client")
    private List<geolocalisation> listeGeolocalisations=new ArrayList<geolocalisation>();


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="IdVille_usr")
    private Ville Ville_Utilisateur;

    //dÃ©claration
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="Transporteur",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Declaration> listeDeclaration=new ArrayList<Declaration>();


    //clients
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="client",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Paiement> listePaiement=new ArrayList<Paiement>();

    private String CodePost_usr;
    private String Rue_usr;
    private String Telephone_usr;
    private String Mobile_usr;
    private Long CID;
    private Date dateCr;
    //commentaire
    @Lob @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
    private String Comment;

    //champs pour un client proffessionnel

    public List<Paiement> getListePaiement() {
        return listePaiement;
    }


    public void setListePaiement(List<Paiement> listePaiement) {
        this.listePaiement = listePaiement;
    }




    private String position;
    //proffessionnelle ou privï¿½
    private String Type_client;

    //Transporteur ou expediteur
    private String TranExp;

    //ï¿½ propos de la sociï¿½tï¿½
    private String Nom_Societe;
    private String Details_Societe;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private Langue langue;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idIndustrie")
    private Industrie industrie;

    //type de service local national international pour un transporteur
    private String ServiceType;

    //ville societe
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="IdVille_Societe")
    private  Ville ville_Societe;

    private String CodePost_Societe;
    private String Rue_Societe;

    private String Telephone_societe;
    private String Fax;
    private String Organization_Number;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="Client",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    List<GLN> list_GLN=new ArrayList<GLN>();

    //assurance
    private String Assurance_Societe;
    private String Assurance_Adresse;
    private String Assurance_Policy_Number;
    private String Assurance_montant;
    private String Assurance_Contact_phone;
    private Date Asssurance_Expiration;



    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idVille_Postal")
    private Ville ville_postal;

    private String CodePost_Postal;
    private String Rue_Postal;


    //Expediteur
    private String Web_Site;

    //Transporteur


    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private  List<TransportCat> listTransportTrCat=new ArrayList<TransportCat>();
```

in the class user is the last association in the class where you have many to many and also in the class carrier is the last association
and thank you for help

Comment: Post your entities and your real code. JPQL doesn't care about tables. It uses entities and their associations. Don't assume JPQL is the same thing as SQL. It's not.

Comment: I was about to answer, after editing your question to make the code readable, but you just removed your code. Sigh.

Comment: i edited now ,if you can help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment: JPQL never uses table and column names. Always entity names and their fields/associations.

```
select c from client c
```

This is already wrong. The entity is named `Client`, not `client`.

```
inner join c.utilisateur_transportcat
```

This is wrong again: there is no field named `utilisateur_transportcat` in the `Client` class.

You simply want a join between the Client entity and its associated TransportCat. The association between those two entities is defined as

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<TransportCat> listTransportTrCat = new ArrayList<TransportCat>();
```

So the query is simply

```
select c from Client c
join c.listTransportTrCat tc
inner join tc.transport t
where t.intitule = 'byroad'
```

I would strongly advise to learn the Java naming conventions and stick to them. All your fields use a different one: `iconImage` (correct), `Statut` (incorrect: should start with lowercase), `Telephone_societe`(incorrect: should not have an underscore, should be telephoneSociete`),`CID` (incorrect: all caps are reserved to constants).

Also choose a language, English preferrably, and stick to it as well, instead of mixing French and English words randomly. For fields of type List, don't name the field listXXX. Simply use the plural form:

```
private List<Paiement> paiements = new ArrayList<Paiement>();
```

Don't use abbraviations. TransportCat doesn't mean anything. If Cat means Category, then name the class TransportCategory.

Naming things correctly is VERY important. You will constantly make mistakes everywhere if you name all your fields in a different way, because you'll never remember how you named them. And the code is painful to read as is.

Comment: thank youuuuuuu for your answer and for your remarks JB Nizet